# iOS Camera Capture Session code works on iOS but not Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, mac-catalyst

I have this block of code that's used for setting up input/output for a video session. It works perfectly on iOS.

```
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    guard let cameraDevice = device.device,
          let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice),
          self.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput),
          self.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {
        log("FrameExtractor error: could not setup input or output.")
        return
    }

    self.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))
    self.addOutput(videoOutput)

    guard let connection = videoOutput.connection(with: CAMERA_FEED_MEDIA_TYPE),
          connection.isVideoOrientationSupported,
          connection.isVideoMirroringSupported else {
        log("FrameExtractor: configureSession: Cannot establish connection")
        return
    }

    if let videoOrientation = getCameraOrientation(device: device) {
        connection.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
    }

    // Mirroring the front camera normalizes the display output for iPad's front camera
    connection.isVideoMirrored = position == .front
```

When run on Catalyst, however, I get a consistent crash at

`self.addOutput(videoOutput)` of

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: index>=0 && index<[_currentItems count]'`